# how to get data for two tables in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was working with Laravel and got stuck in a situation. I have following tables:
student table and relation table
student table has the following columns 
id,name,sex,age,and class

relation table has the following columns 
id,id_student_girl,id_student_boy and status

i need to display output look like this:
name_student_girl,name_student_boy and status

code i tried :

```
$query =DB::table('student')
            ->join('relation','relation.id_student_girl', '=', 'student.id')
            ->join('relation','relation .id_student_boy ', '=', 'student.id')
            ->select('student.*','relation.*')
            ->get();
```

I got errors on this query Any idea, how to achieve this. I hope I was able to clear my situation. Thanks

Comment: Post your error pls

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias

Comment: Use unique table aliases `join('relation as r1', 'r1.id_student_girl' ... )`. But that won't be your last problem with that query.

Comment: It is giving null output

Comment: Thats because a student can probably not be a girl and a boy at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query =DB::table('student')
->join('relation', function($join)
{
    $join->on('relation.id_student_girl', '=', 'student.id')
       ->orOn('relation.id_student_boy ', '=', 'student.id');
})->select('student.*','relation.*')->get();
```

Even if this does work, I think it's a very bad database structure that you have. Why does your relation table have a id_student_boy and id_student_girl column? Is there a relationship between the 2 columns?

Comment: yes i thought what are the  best advice , making two tables one for girls and other for boys

Comment: I think it's best you come up with a better database design.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all relational data so easily with this code..

```
App\Student::with('relation')->get();
```

but for run this code you need to describe your table  relation in your model.
check this

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: Student::with('relation')->get();